# dbcc checkdb errors, or msg 601 when restoring SQL 2012 backup to SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, restore, dbcc

I need to move two databases, WES and WILL from a Win2012/SQL2012 instance to a Win2016/SQL2016 instance for a software upgrade. I'm using the full backup files from the SQL2012 maintenance plans. I've verified I can restore them to the original SQL2012 instance with no errors.

Restoring WES to SQL2016 reports no errors, but dbcc checkdb shows errors:

> Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 13
> Table error: Object ID 60, index ID 1, partition ID 281474980642816, alloc unit ID 281474980642816 (type In-row data), page (1:453). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -4.
> ...etc

Restoring WILL to SQL2016 stops partway through the upgrade steps with

> Database 'WILL' running the upgrade step from version 805 to version 806.
> Msg 601, Level 12, State 3, Line 2
> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.

I thought the upgrade between versions was automatic. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Does DBCC CHECKDB come back clean when you run it on the SQL Server 2012 instance?

Comment: Yes it does. I've since tried restoring to Win2016/SQL2012 Express on the new server with similar results. So it seems to be something with the source server, and not so much with the different versions.

Comment: On the SQL2012 instance, dbcc is clean on both the original db, as well as the newly created db i created from the restore.

Comment: Would you add the DBCC page output (specifically the page header) to the question, please?

Comment: have you tried running DBCC in SQL 2012? Is there any record in msdb..suspect_pages? It seems you have data corruption.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie I run DBCC CHECKDB daily for both WES and WILL in the source instance. No errors reported. You may be onto something with msdb..suspect_pages...there are a total of 163 records present, all for WILL, from 2018. All are event_type 4 or 7, which I believe mean they've been addressed successfully. Is there any other check I can do for corruption in the source?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was introduced as soon as I copied the file from one system to the other. The MD5 checksum was different each time I tried to copy.

I could successfully restore the database to the new server only when the MD5 checksums matched.

> C:\GPCentral>certutil -hashfile \sql2\c$\backup\GP\DYNAMICS\DYNAMICS.bak MD5
> MD5 hash of file \sql2\c$\backup\GP\DYNAMICS\DYNAMICS.bak:
> **4aec5a57a83bbb14e7bb9d5b038e0dee**
> CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
>
> C:\GPCentral>xcopy \sql2\c$\backup\GP\DYNAMICS\DYNAMICS.bak . /j /v /y
> \sql2\c$\backup\GP\DYNAMICS\DYNAMICS.bak
> 1 File(s) copied
>
> C:\GPCentral>certutil -hashfile .\DYNAMICS.bak MD5
> MD5 hash of file .\DYNAMICS.bak:
> **50bba7fbeae579567b95166a1950e25e**
> CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
>
> C:\GPCentral>xcopy \sql2\c$\backup\GP\DYNAMICS\DYNAMICS.bak . /j /v /y
> \sql2\c$\backup\GP\DYNAMICS\DYNAMICS.bak
> 1 File(s) copied
>
> C:\GPCentral>certutil -hashfile .\DYNAMICS.bak MD5
> MD5 hash of file .\DYNAMICS.bak:
> **eb4e1b214e197939c2e7e1aa9a29d9ab**
> CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
>
> C:\GPCentral>

I still need to investigate why this is happening, but wanted to mark this question answered.